# What's the best practice in Golang to track the done status of two goroutines in a third goroutine?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have three goroutines running concurrently. Two of these do some processing and send their results to a results channel. The third goroutine "tallies" results by reading the results channel. I could use a waitgroup to wait for the two computational goroutines to finish, then range over the results channel to tally the results, but this wouldn't scale and would require me to create a buffered results channel with a massive buffer size which is unacceptable in production code.

I want to tally the results AS the processing occurs, but I don't want to exit the program until all tallying is complete. What is the best practice for achieving this in Go?

Here is my current approach that works just fine. I'm wondering whether there is a better way, since this seems a little clunky?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type T struct{}

func main() {
    var widgetInventory int = 1000
    transactions := make(chan int, 100)
    salesDone := make(chan T)
    purchasesDone := make(chan T)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fmt.Println("Starting inventory count = ", widgetInventory)

    go makeSales(transactions, salesDone)
    go newPurchases(transactions, purchasesDone)

    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        salesAreDone := false
        purchasesAreDone := false

        for {
            select {
            case transaction := <-transactions:
                widgetInventory += transaction
            case <-salesDone:
                salesAreDone = true
            case <-purchasesDone:
                purchasesAreDone = true
            default:
                if salesAreDone && purchasesAreDone {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Ending inventory count = ", widgetInventory)
}

func makeSales(transactions chan int, salesDone chan T) {
    for i := 0; i < 3000; i++ {
        transactions <- -100
    }

    salesDone <- struct{}{}
}

func newPurchases(transactions chan int, purchasesDone chan T) {
    for i := 0; i < 3000; i++ {
        transactions <- 100
    }

    purchasesDone <- struct{}{}
}
```

Comment: There is none. Typical approaches are `sync.WaitGroup` and a channel from which the "waiting" goroutine do two reads (that is, it uses explicit counting, not `for ... := range channel`).

Comment: Assuming I understand your explanation correctly, you're saying that I should initialize an integer counter in my third goroutine with a value of 0, then increment it when each of the calculating goroutines complete. In the default portion of my select {} block, I check whether that integer == 2 and, if so, I call wg.Done() and break out of the loop or just return from the goroutine?

Comment: No, you do `wg.Add(2)` in the waiting goroutine, then spawn your two goroutines passing each a pointer to that WaitGroup, and then make each call `Done` on the WG after each has finished its task (as far as the waiting goroutine should be concerned). Usually this is done in a `defer`red call in the goroutine. The waiting goroutine calls `Wait` on the WG which blocks and gets unblocked as soon as the calls to `Done` in both the worker goroutines drop the counter maintained by the WG back to 0 (from 2).

Comment: Consider reading [these series](https://www.google.com/search?q=concurrency+patterns%3A+site%3Ago.dev%2Fblog) in any case.

Comment: I cannot use waitgroups in the third goroutine to block until the other two goroutines have finished executing. The third goroutine must tally the inventory levels while the other two goroutines are working, so that I don't build up insane levels of results in the results pipeline (which would have to have a crazy buffer size, depending on how much work was being done in the real world). I am reading the series you posted though!

Comment: Maybe consider an approach [like this](https://go.dev/play/p/ccXse2_jLzo) (there is no right way of doing this, but using channel closure to signal the end of input data can simplify things).

Comment: «I cannot use waitgroups in the third goroutine to block until the other two goroutines have finished executing. The third goroutine must tally the inventory levels while the other two goroutines are working,»–then use a bufered channel (with capacity 2) and make the waiting goroutine read from that channel exactly twice once it will have finished its task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is my current approach that works just fine

Not for any reasonable definition of *just fine*.  You have a hot `for` loop here:

```
for {
            select {
            case transaction := <-transactions:
                widgetInventory += transaction
            case <-salesDone:
                salesAreDone = true
            case <-purchasesDone:
                purchasesAreDone = true
            default:
                if salesAreDone && purchasesAreDone {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
```

The `default` case executes *whenever* no channels are ready to read.  Because of the way channels work, this happens quite a lot.

[This slightly adjusted version of your code illustrates the "heat" of this loop.](https://go.dev/play/p/njaMNcCgj1-)  Exact results will vary, could be quite high.

```
Default case ran 27305 times
```

You don't want a `default` case when `select`ing from channels unless that default case will also block on something inside it.  Otherwise you get a hot loop like this.

#### A better way: select with `nil`able channels

[Generally in a select, you want to identify closed channels and set the channel variable to `nil`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666253/breaking-out-of-a-select-statement-when-all-channels-are-closed); `select` will never successfully read from a `nil` channel so this essentially "disables" that selection.

Consider [this modified version of your code](https://go.dev/play/p/d5GWvBoASQd):

```
    go func(transactions chan int, salesDone <-chan T, purchasesDone <-chan T) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for transactions != nil {
            select {
            case transaction, ok := <-transactions:
                if ok {
                    widgetInventory += transaction
                } else {
                    transactions = nil
                }
            case <-salesDone:
                salesDone = nil
                if purchasesDone == nil {
                    close(transactions)
                }
            case <-purchasesDone:
                purchasesDone = nil
                if salesDone == nil {
                    close(transactions)
                }

            }
        }
    }(transactions, salesDone, purchasesDone)
```

With these adjustments to the consumer, we don't have a hot loop; we always block until we read from a channel.  Once both `salesDone` and `purchasesDone` have been "signaled", we `close(transactions)`.  Once we have drained `transactions` *and* it is closed, we set `transactions` to nil.  We loop while `transactions` is not nil, which in this code, implies all channels are `nil`.

A subtle but important point: I pass the channels to this function so its references do not share scope with `main`.  Otherwise, setting `transactions` to `nil` would be writing a variable that's shared across goroutines.  However in this case, it doesn't matter anyway because we "know" we're the last one to read from `transactions`.

#### A simpler option: multiple wait groups

If you think about what you're doing here, you want to wait until both producers are done producing to `transactions`.  Then you want to drain `transactions`.  Once the channel is closed and drained, `main` knows the summation is complete.

You don't need `select` to do that.  And `select` with a case for each "worker", so to speak, is quite inelegant; you have to hard code a number of workers and individually handle the "Done" channels.

All you need to do is:

- Add a `var resultswg sync.WaitGroup` for the consumer, in addition to using one for the producers.
- the producers `defer wg.Done()`
- the consumer `defer resultswg.Done()` before ranging over `transactions`:

  ```
  go func() {
      defer resultswg.Done()
      for transaction := range transactions {
          widgetInventory += transaction
      }
  }()
  ```
- main handles waiting on the producers, closing transactions to end the range, and then waiting on the consumer:

  ```
  wg.Wait()
  close(transactions)
  resultswg.Wait()
  ```

[It ends up being short and sweet when coded this way](https://go.dev/play/p/ZJ1znpvar14):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var widgetInventory int = 1000
    transactions := make(chan int, 100)

    var wg, resultswg sync.WaitGroup
    fmt.Println("Starting inventory count = ", widgetInventory)
    wg.Add(2)

    go makeSales(transactions, &wg)
    go newPurchases(transactions, &wg)
    resultswg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer resultswg.Done()
        for transaction := range transactions {
            widgetInventory += transaction
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    close(transactions)
    resultswg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Ending inventory count = ", widgetInventory)
}

func makeSales(transactions chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 3000; i++ {
        transactions <- -100
    }

}

func newPurchases(transactions chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 3000; i++ {
        transactions <- 100
    }

}
```

You can see here that you could have any number of producers in this pattern; you just have to `wg.Add(1)` for each producer.

I use this pattern all the time to parallelize work when I don't know how many results will be returned from each worker.  I find it to be easy to comprehend and a lot simpler than trying to `select` multiple channels.  In fact, I'd go so far as to say that if you find yourself `select`ing from multiple channels, you should step back and make sure it really makes sense for you.  I use `select` far less often than I use wait groups.

Comment: sorry I think that was a reply to a comment which I made and then deleted (when I noticed that you were doing the `wg.Wait()` in the main goroutine). Would not have posted my comment if your answer was visible to me at the time (but do prefer the approach I showed as it groups the operations that may lead to a panic together which I find easier to read). Upvoted your answer.

Comment: Erik: Thank you so much, not just for answering but for pointing out the hot loop and offering an even more elegant alternative. This is fantastic and absolutely answers the question. Much appreciated!